# Angular split a JSON string in template

Tags: angular

My application calls a service that returns messages to the front end.

On the front end I display the messages like so

```
    <div class="col-md-12">

<article class="panel panel-default" [ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: color}" (mouseenter)="color = 'green'">
    <div class="panel-body">


        {{message.content}}<br />
        {{message.orderType}}

    </div>
    <footer class="panel-footer">
        <div class="author">
            {{message.username}}
        </div>
        <div class="config">
            <a (click)="onEdit()">Edit</a>
            <a (click)="onDelete()">Delete</a>
            <a (click)="onComplete()">Complete</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
</article>
</div>
```

This JSON passed back from the call is like this

```
{
  "message": "Success",
  "obj": [
    {
      "_id": "5a512e4b43f7ed0014df8ba6",
      "content": "test1, test2, test3",
      "orderType": "Completed",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5a523895d47c50593595b457",
      "content": "Test1, Test2, Test3",
      "orderType": "Completed",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5a523bf7d47c50593595b458",
      "content": "New order, test1, test2",
      "orderType": "Completed",
      "__v": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

What i'm trying to do is split the `message.content` into an array and then I can display each item in the array on a new line, rather than display one long string.

Comment: And what is your question? If the question is, how to split a string in JavaScript, then https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: I guess the question is, should I write a function in the component.ts file and then call that function from the template, if so can I just pass the string into it? Or can angular do it on the front end for example like it does ngIf or ngFor

Comment: None of the above. You should call it, once and for all, when you receive the JSON, and thus provide a data structure that the view can use directly, without having to split every message again and again at each change detection. Or you can use a pipe, but then you will have the array only in the view, and not in the component where it could be useful, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
"message.content" it is wrong to display. because "content" is not a property of "message"
```

Used following format to display the content in new line.

```
$scope.data = {
  "message": "Success",
  "obj": [
    {
      "_id": "5a512e4b43f7ed0014df8ba6",
      "content": "test1, test2, test3",
      "orderType": "Completed",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5a523895d47c50593595b457",
      "content": "Test1, Test2, Test3",
      "orderType": "Completed",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5a523bf7d47c50593595b458",
      "content": "New order, test1, test2",
      "orderType": "Completed",
      "__v": 0
    }
  ]
}

<div class="col-md-12">
<article class="panel panel-default" [ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: color}" (mouseenter)="color = 'green'">
    <div class="panel-body" >
        <div class="row" ng-repeat="msg in data.obj">
         <p>{{msg.content}}</p>
        <small>{{msg.orderType}}</small>
```

```
    </div>
    <footer class="panel-footer">
        <div class="author">
            {{message.username}}
        </div>
        <div class="config">
            <a (click)="onEdit()">Edit</a>
            <a (click)="onDelete()">Delete</a>
            <a (click)="onComplete()">Complete</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
</article>
</div>
```

Comment: That just repeats what I have now. For context I call the component from another <div *ngFor="let message of messages">
                    <div *ngIf="message.orderType == 'Processing'">
                        
                           

                        <app-message
                        [message]="message" 
                        (editClicked)="message.content= $event"
                        >
                        </app-message>
                    </div>
                </div> so nothing wrong with displaying data, was just looking at splitting strings